# Adding bold tags to a string of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have a string of html in javascript/jquery.

```
var str = '<div id="cheese" class="appleSauce"> I like <a href="apple.com"> apple </a> and cheese</div>';
```

I want to make the string 'apple' bold.  So I do:

```
str = str.replace('apple','<b>apple</b>');
```

but this breaks the html part of the string.  I get:

```
<div id="cheese" class="<b>apple</b>Sauce"> I like <a href="<b>apple</b>.com"><b>apple</b></a> and cheese</div>
```

How can I replace all occurrences of a string in the text of an html string without changing the matches inside of html markup?

Comment: you need to replace text of the tag, not all the text in the string. otherwise you can use " apple " - space before and after the word.

Comment: Can you break up the string and concatenate?

Comment: Do you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Create an element, jQuery element in this case, and set the innerHTML property:

```
var el = $('<div id="cheese" class="appleSauce"> I like apple and cheese</div>');

el.html(el.html().replace('apple','<b>apple</b>'));
```

Comment: I tried: var el = $('<div id="cheese" class="appleSauce"> I like apple and cheese</div>');  alert(el.html); and it returns "function(1){....}"  -- not the html inside of element el

Comment: Ok that worked in this specific case. but in the more general case it fails.  What about this str:  str ="I like <a href='http://a.com'>apples</a> and cheese!"; And I want to do str.replace('a','<b>a</b>');

Comment: Also, your answer only returns the string inside the '<div>' tags.

Comment: to perform the more general case, you'll need to a regex replace. and `.html()` returns the HTML contents of a particular element, what were you expecting?

Comment: I want to get back the whole string I started with.

Answer (score 1):

```
var e = $('#cheese');
e.html(e.text().replace('apple','<b>apple</b>'));
```

<kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hmzwz/)</kbd>

Comment: I haven't put the string inside of an element yet.  But this could be the only way to do it.

Comment: you should be setting the `innerHTML` and not the `innerText`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that

`var str=str.replace(new RegExp(/(apple)$/),"<b>apple</b>");`